# Edit Form read only to submitter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I would like to make the edit from disabled/ read only to submitter after they have submit the item. Is there a way to do so? I've tried setting workflow to "View Only" for people/ picker but somehow the submitter is not able to view listed items. I am using SharePoint 2013 and workflow 2010. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please note that we cannot set *Edit form* to Read Only. If a user loses the ability to edit an item, he/she will only be able to open the *Display Form* and lose access to the *Edit form*.

Here is a sample workflow for your reference:

[image]

You will need to deactivate **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode** feature under Site Collection Features and **Workflows can use app permissions** feature under Site Features.

Set the workflow to run on item creation and the submitter will be granted View Only permission on item level when the workflow completes.

Reference:
[How to Set Item Level Permission Using SharePoint Designer 2010 Work Flow.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it and noticed that others cannot see the created items from requester.

Comment: @Madeline Have you checked the item permission after the workflow finishes running? Please confirm if the permission has been successfully replaced before we troubleshoot this issue.